# In Vue 3 project Form Object array value is not updated

Tags: vuejs3

In my vue 3 project I added the radio button and that button click I hide and show td and update the value of cust_feedback_rating but its show the undefined but when I check in console its show me

Here we added the some code below

```
<template>
  <div>
     <td v-if="showFilled === 2 && !anyDedicatedProject && tl_rating">
<div>
    <Field type="number" :min="0" :max="5" name="cust_feedback_rating"
        class="form-control"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.cust_feedback_rating }"
        v-model="form.cust_feedback_rating"></Field>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.cust_feedback_rating }}</div>
</div><br>
<div>
    <Field type="number" :min="0" :max="5" name="cust_feedback_eff_rating"
        disabled class="form-control"
        v-model="formEffectiveData.cust_feedback_eff_rating"></Field>
</div>
</td>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        manager_feedback: '',
        task_execution: 0,
        unit_testing: 0,
        coding_standard: 0,
        pm_rating: 0,
        communication: 0,
        tech_dev: 0,
        mockup_rating: 0,
        html_rating: 0,
        quality_rating: 0,
        cust_feedback_rating: 0,
        bug_rating: 0,
        test_plan_rating: 0,
        process: 0,
      },
    };
  },
  watch: {
    'form.cust_feedback_rating': function (newValue, oldValue) {
      this.form.cust_feedback_rating = 5;
    
      console.log('data', this.form.cust_feedback_rating)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello shark In your code the issue regarding the Dom object, when you assign the data of object array that time your Dom element is not refresh that why cust_feedback_rating variable show undefined

Here Do the following changes in your code

1. Replace the v-if condtion with v-show

   ```js
   <td v-show="showFilled === 2 && !anyDedicatedProject && tl_rating">
   ```

2.Replace watch method code like below.

```js
    'form.cust_feedback_rating': function (newValue, oldValue) {
      this.form = { ...this.form, cust_feedback_rating: newValue };
      console.log('data', this.form.cust_feedback_rating)
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the nextTick(); to update the DOM`

```js
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue'
```

`